# React-style way to manage className and forms

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am a professional Angular developer and start to learn React. [This](https://github.com/Triplecorpse/thenewword2-front/tree/f96c5f0fe60e635feaf2ede5863901057341679b) is my repo to be reviewed.

This is a small login/register form created with React. I want to check if this small project actually is written with React-style. If you don't feel comfortable to open and look into repository, I place the most issued files here.

1. Dynamically adding classes. As I got, there is no declarative way as in angular `[class.xxx]="true"`, I need to create class string elsewhere and bind it to the element.
2. The second file is a form. It is almost HTML way so I am also interested if it is React-style.

I would appreciate if you look the whole repository that consists of login/register form only. But if you don't want to do it for some reason, I would appreciate to review these files also.

```
import './Login.component.scss';
import * as React from "react";
import LoginFormComponent from "./LoginForm.component";
import WelcomeComponent from "./Welcome.component";
import RegisterFormComponent from "./RegisterForm.component";

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.register = this.register.bind(this)
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            loginFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper'],
            registerFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper', 'hidden', 'register']
        }
    }

    register() {
        this.setState({
            loginFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper', 'hidden'],
            registerFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper']
        });
    }

    login() {
        this.setState({
            loginFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper'],
            registerFormWrapperClasses: ['form-wrapper', 'hidden', 'register']
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="background">
                <div className={this.state.loginFormWrapperClasses.join(' ')}>
                    <LoginFormComponent apiLink="http://localhost:5000/" register={this.register}/>
                </div>
                <div className={this.state.registerFormWrapperClasses.join(' ')}>
                    <RegisterFormComponent apiLink="http://localhost:5000/" login={this.login}/>
                </div>
                <div className="welcome-wrapper">
                    <WelcomeComponent />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

```
import './LoginForm.component.scss';
import * as React from "react";

class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login: '',
            password: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="login-form-component" >
                <form className="form" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                    <label>
                        Ім'я користувача
                        <input type="text" name="login" value={this.state.login} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Гасло
                        <input type="password" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    </label>
                    <div className="actions">
                        <button type="button" className="register" onClick={this.props.register}>Зареєструватися</button>
                        <button type="submit">Продовжити</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

    submit(e) {
        const body = {
            login: this.state.login,
            password: this.state.password
        };

        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(this.props.apiLink + 'user/login', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
        });
    }
}

export default LoginFormComponent;
```

Comment: Welcome to code review! You have done a pretty good job on this question so far. We can only review code that is in the question. Repositories are good as a reference, but we can't review the code in them.